# PROC FCMP returns incorrect length of string

Tags: sas

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.func.conversion;
function upper_vn(province $) $;
length new_province $200; 
    if province in ("TỈNH QuẢNG NINH", "TỈNH QUẢNG NINH") then new_province = "TỈNH QUẢNG NINH";
    if province in ("TỈNH THỪA THIÊN HUẾ","TỈNH THỪA THIÊN-HUẾ","TỈNH THỪA THIÊN-HuẾ") then new_province = "TỈNH THỪA THIÊN HUẾ";
    if province in ("TỈNH TiỀN GIANG","TỈNH TIỀN GIANG") then new_province = "TỈNH TIỀN GIANG";
    else new_province = province;
return (new_province);
endsub;
run; 
options cmplib=(work.func); 

data test; 
length test_string $ 50; 
input test_string & $;
datalines;
"TỈNH THỪA THIÊN-HUẾ"
"TỈNH TIỀN GIANG";
run; 


data output;
set test;
length test_string $ 50;
length newprovince $ 50;
newprovince = upper_vn(test_string );
run;
```

So I create a function in SAS but the result output doesn't return full length of the output string.
What could possibly wrong?

Comment: You are calling a different function than you defined.

Comment: Thanks Tom, how silly am I. The code is edited

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Tom's comment above, you need to declare the length of new_province within the function as well as the output length of the function.

```
proc fcmp outlib=work.func.conversion;
function Unify_Agc(province $) $ 200;
    length province new_province $200;
    if province in ("TỈNH QuẢNG NINH", "TỈNH QUẢNG NINH") then new_province = "TỈNH QUẢNG NINH";
    if province in ("TỈNH THỪA THIÊN HUẾ","TỈNH THỪA THIÊN-HUẾ","TỈNH THỪA THIÊN-HuẾ") then new_province = "TỈNH THỪA THIÊN HUẾ";
    if province in ("TỈNH TiỀN GIANG","TỈNH TIỀN GIANG") then new_province = "TỈNH TIỀN GIANG";
    else new_province = province;
return (new_province);
endsub;
run; 
options cmplib=(work.func);
```